# Jquery - Button onclick target closest input and get value

Tags: jquery, html

I want to use both the forms with same class name for buttons & inputs based on design.

If i click 1 button, it triggers both the form and sending "empty" value.

Is it possible to target "closest" input on button click by jquery method.

Please let me know comments or inputs to solve this issue?

Thanks

**HTML:**

```
<form>
<div class="loginMHNo">
  <input class="login-MH--no" type="text" name="MHNumber" />
</div>
<div class="loginPassword">
  <input class="login-MH--password" name="Password" type="password"  />
</div>
  <button class="loginSubmit btn" type="submit">Login</button>
 </form>


<form>
<div class="loginMHNo">
  <input class="login-MH--no" type="text" name="MHNumber" />
</div>
<div class="loginPassword">
  <input class="login-MH--password" name="Password" type="password"  />
</div>
  <button class="loginSubmit btn" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$(this).closest('form')` to get the `closest()` form when you click on the submit button and use `$(this).closest('form').serialize()` to get the serialized values filled in that form:

```js
$(".loginSubmit").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var closestForm = $(this).closest('form');
  console.log($(this).closest('form').serialize())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="loginMHNo">
    <input class="login-MH--no" type="text" name="MHNumber" />
  </div>
  <div class="loginPassword">
    <input class="login-MH--password" name="Password" type="password" />
  </div>
  <button class="loginSubmit btn" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>


<form>
  <div class="loginMHNo">
    <input class="login-MH--no" type="text" name="MHNumber" />
  </div>
  <div class="loginPassword">
    <input class="login-MH--password" name="Password" type="password" />
  </div>
  <button class="loginSubmit btn" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

İf you change button like :

loginSubmit type submit to button and onclick event `(onclick="login_clicked(this)")` function is ;

```
function login_clicked(_this){
   var params = $(_this).closest("form").serialize();
   ajax...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use code like this:

```
$('.loginSubmit').click(function(){
  $(this).parents('form').serialize();
});
```

If you want to submit the form

```
$('.loginSubmit').click(function(){
  $(this).parents('form').submit();
});
//to submit the particular forms
```

Here is documentation for [`serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function and for [`parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) function.